# Setting a "function pointer"-like member to a noexcept lambda

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member, std-function

I cannot achieve the effect in title, as implemented in the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define USEFUNPTR
#define USESTDFUN

class Dummy {
   public:
#ifdef USEFUNPTR
    void (*Foo)() noexcept = nullptr;
#endif
#ifdef USESTDFUN
    std::function<void() noexcept> Bar;
#endif
    void InitFuns() {
#ifdef USEFUNPTR
        Foo = []() noexcept { std::cout << "Foo\n" << std::endl; };
#endif
#ifdef USESTDFUN
        Bar = []() noexcept { std::cout << "Bar\n" << std::endl; };
#endif
    };

    ~Dummy() noexcept = default;
};};
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/v7jexd1ez)
with `USEFUNPTR` defined:
In C++14, msvc refuses the function pointer version:

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Dummy::InitFuns::<lambda_b40e7171393910f4bba39b7be19bf362>' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void) noexcept'

with `USESTDFUN` defined:
In C++17 `gcc`, `clang` and `msvc` reject the `std::function` version:
`gcc`:

> error: field 'Bar' has incomplete type 'std::function<void() noexcept>'
> 13 |     std::function<void() noexcept> Bar;
> `msvc`:
> error C2338: static_assert failed: 'std::function does not accept noexcept function types as template arguments.'

`msvc` is more explicit and indicates that, from C++17, `std::function` seems unable to wrap a `noexcept` function (there is indeed no prototype of `std::function` with `noexcept` and this specifier is part of the type from C++17, if I understood correctly (from some other SO post):

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Dummy::InitFuns::<lambda_b40e7171393910f4bba39b7be19bf362>' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void) noexcept'

How can I achieve this functionality in a way that works in all C++>=14, and with all compilers?
(In an actual usecase, the InitFuns may have runtime and/or compile time parameters and the lambda definition will depend on these parameters, yet the code that will call `Foo` or `Bar` is unaware of these parameters).

NB I found several posts indicating that a lambda cannot decay to a function pointer member but I didn't understand why and if they were a workaround to achieve this functionnality.

Comment: The exception specification is part of function type, but not part of the function signature.  (At least as of C++17.)

Comment: std::function does not play nice with noexcept (it doesn't specialize on it). Which I still think is a defect. What is it that you want to achieve? Do you want to be able to only accept lambdas that are noexcept or do you need a function pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need ```noexcept```. For information, an actual usecase is on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286755/reusable-storage-for-array-of-objects). The lambda is holding code that is to be used inside the class destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a kind of workaround, that lets you detect if the lambda is noexcept before you assign it to a std::function<void()>.
Another option is to wrap a try/catch block around any noexcept function (runtime detections, so suboptimal)

Example here :

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

// noexcept will not be picked up by std::function
// but with SFINAE you can detect the noexcept

using function_ptr_t = void (*)() noexcept;

namespace traits
{
    template<typename fn_t>
    using is_noexcept_fn = std::enable_if_t<noexcept(std::declval<fn_t>()()), fn_t>;

    template<typename fn_t>
    static constexpr bool is_noexcept_fn_ptr()
    {
        return std::is_convertible_v<fn_t, function_ptr_t> && noexcept(std::declval<fn_t>());
    }

    template<typename fn_t>
    using is_noexcept_fn_ptr_t = std::enable_if_t<is_noexcept_fn_ptr<fn_t>(), fn_t>;
}

class Dummy
{
public:
    // Only accept the lambda (function object) if it has a noexcept operator()
    template<typename fn_t, typename enable_t = traits::is_noexcept_fn_ptr_t<fn_t>>
    explicit Dummy(fn_t fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    }

    void operator()() noexcept
    {
        m_fn();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_fn;
};

class Dummy2
{
public:
    // other option is to actually catch all exceptions for 
    // functions that are not noexcept
    template<typename fn_t>
    explicit Dummy2(fn_t fn)
    {
        if constexpr (noexcept(fn()))
        {
            m_fn = fn;
        }
        else
        {
            auto lambda = [=]()
            {
                try
                {
                    fn();
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    std::cout << "unhandled exeption caught\n";
                }
            };

            m_fn = lambda;
        }
    }

    void operator()() noexcept
    {
        m_fn();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_fn;
};

class Dummy3
{
public:
    // Only accept a function pointer if it is a noexcept operator()
    template<typename fn_t, typename enable_t = traits::is_noexcept_fn_ptr_t<fn_t>>
    explicit Dummy3(fn_t fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    }

    void operator()() noexcept
    {
        m_fn();
    }

private:
    function_ptr_t m_fn;
};


void test() noexcept
{
    std::cout << "free function\n";
};

int main()
{
    //Dummy d1{ [] { std::cout << "does not compile\n"; } };
    Dummy d{ []() noexcept { std::cout << "does compile\n"; } };
    d();

    Dummy2 d2{ [] { throw std::runtime_error{"oops"}; } };
    d2();

    Dummy3 d3_lambda{ []() noexcept { std::cout << "using lmabda's function pointer\n"; } };
    d3_lambda();

    Dummy3 d3_free_function(test);
    d3_free_function();

    // indeed fails to compile
    //Dummy3 d3_lambda_fail{ [] { std::cout << "using lmabda's function pointer\n"; } };
    //d3_lambda();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting but it think it does not answer my need. I must support the noexcept as the caller may require ```noexcept```, whereas you "cast" away the ```noexcept``` specification, don't you?

Comment: I should have added the noexcept to operator()(). Noexcept is now a strong guarantee for the std::function<void()> member variable even if indeed it erases the noexcept detail. I don't see this as a problem, it is a common pattern in type erasure.

Comment: Note I added `noexcept` to operator()() in the example

Comment: If I understand well. Your solution is a workaround for the ```std::function``` case:
1- "cast" away the ```noexcept specification``` if any
2- at call point, if caller is ```noexcept``` make the ```std::function``` functor noexcept again through try-catch.
I over-simplify (for instance, in order to be the most generic, it might be useful to track if the passed lambda was originally noexcept)
Correct?

Comment: I myself favor Dummy over Dummy2 since it does compile time validation. For option2 It is not so much casting away as just creating a function object (std::function just ignores the noexcept part). I think in the end you could say Dummy one is a std::function wrapper that guarantees noexceptness. I see no reason to track the noexceptness of the original function but it could be done (for debug purposes). (I am not sure if I am really helping you with this comment, mainly just describing to my thinking).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm just wondering what the standard says about calling a non ```noexcept``` function within a ```noexcept``` one?

Comment: PepijnKramer proposal is interesting for the ```std::function``` case. Yet as it cames with an overhead (at least the use of ```std::function``` itself) has anyone a function pointer -based solution? Is msvc right to reject the code or is it a bug?

Comment: Updated the example to have Dummy3 a which uses a function pointer

Comment: Thx but it still does not compile with msvc C++14. Besides the issue (in my case) seems to come from the lambda being declared inside a member function. Your example does not cover this case.

Comment: I Forgot to check C++14

Comment: C++14 version of Dummy3 here : https://onlinegdb.com/9bSwHN066 (I only needed to replace `std::is_convertible_v<fn_t, function_ptr_t>` with `std::is_convertible<fn_t, function_ptr_t>::value`

Comment: I add fixed that but msvc gives "error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration". Besides, my issue will probably be not reproducible with your example as the lambdas are not declared inside a member function. You may see the error reported, in this situation, in the original question.

Comment: Interesting I don't see that error. Using visual studio 2022, 17.7.1, and compiling with C++14. Anyway maybe you can get some ideas from this :)

Comment: I posted a followup question about the [msvc issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050472/setting-a-function-pointer-member-to-a-lambda-issue-with-msvc-c14). It is solved in the comments.